# How can I register webservice through OSGi (karaf) API with custom trustManager

Tags: java, ssl, osgi

I am working on software which registers WS through the call below:

```
initiatingBundle.getBundleContext()
    .registerService(
          interfaces,
          serviceObject,
          this.convertMapToDictionary(
                initiatingBundle.getBundleContext(),
                serviceAttributes
          )
    );
```

This is the [help for the OSGi API](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html#registerService%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.util.Dictionary%29):

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleContext
ServiceRegistration<?> registerService(java.lang.String[] clazzes,
                                   java.lang.Object service,
                                   java.util.Dictionary<java.lang.String,?> properties)
```

Is there any way (example with the properties attribute) to create a webservice with custom TrustManager like below?

```
TrustManager trustManager = new X509TrustManager() {

                            @Override public void checkClientTrusted( X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s ) throws CertificateException {
                                    System.out.println( "=== interception point at checkClientTrusted ===" );
                                    System.out.println( x509Certificates[0].getSubjectDN().getName() );
                                    System.out.println( "================================================" );
                                    throw new CertificateException( "interception point at checkClientTrusted" );
                            }

                            @Override public void checkServerTrusted( X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s ) throws CertificateException {
                                    System.out.println( "checkServerTrusted" );
                            }

                            @Override public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                                    return new X509Certificate[0];
                            }
                    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Karaf uses Pax Web for the HttpService implementation, plus a lot more. 
In general a X509certificate will be needed if a SSL based connection is used. So you just need to configure the HttpService accordingly to the OSGi spec and with special Pax Web properties.

To enable SSL support you must set the following properties:
**org.osgi.service.http.secure.enabled** to **true**
**org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.keystore** to the path to the keystore to be used. If not set the default path ${user.home}/.keystore is used.
**org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.password** to the password used for keystore integrity check. The value can be in plain text or obfuscated ( starting with OBF: ) as described in step 4 of jetty docummentation
**org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.keypassword** to the password used for keystore. The value can be in plain text or obfuscated ( starting with OBF: ) as described in step 4 of jetty docummentation
You may also set the following:
**org.osgi.service.http.port.secure** to change the port. Default is **8443**.

Additionally for Certificates you'll need to set the following: 
**org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.clientauthwanted**=wanted
This property specifies, if certificate-based client authentication at the server is **"wanted"**.

**org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.clientauthneeded**=required
This property specifies, if certificate-based client authentication at the server is **"required"**.

More details may be found at the [Pax Web](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxweb/SSL+Configuration) project. Also there are samples available at the projects [GitHub](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/blob/master/pax-web-itest/pax-web-itest-container/pax-web-itest-container-jetty/src/test/java/org/ops4j/pax/web/itest/jetty/WarBasicAuthSecuredIntegrationTest.java) Project.

Comment: Thank you, that was very usefull, but the question was about custom trustmanager. I want to handle the client cert check step during the TLS handshake myself...for example: not based only on issuer but based on other attributes. Is it possible with the OSGi API?

Comment: In that case you'll need to change the jetty.xml to use your custom manager. Make sure to enable ssl through configuration and jetty.xml. Because of this you can alter the default config. Details can also be found at pax web documentation or samples and integration tests.

Comment: As I can see I can only set attributes in jetty.xml which are related to the org.eclipse.jetty package. Unfortunatelly org.eclipse.jetty.ssl.SSLContext and SSLContextFactory have no attribute for trustManager (only a static member which is overwritten if any truststore is given and it is configured in OSGi). On this link[http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html#registerService%28java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.Object,%20java.util.Dictionary%29] I am curious about the dict keys,values. Maybe there is a config for custom TrustManager...

Comment: no I don't think that's a working solution. In case that you're using the HttpService Registration of the Servlets (or by Whiteboard means) you are able to register your own HttpContext, it requires to have a handleSecurity() method. You might be able to place your own TrustManager there. The handleSecurity will give you the request and response objects, so you might get a hold of the client certificate in that.