# Enable / disable allowed cipher suites in Apache Karaf with Pax (including Jetty)

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, apache-karaf, pax-web

I am using Apache Karaf to host my web service. I enabled SSL connections through the Karaf client with the commands shown below post start up since I have multiple servers running the same code but with different certificates and configurations.

[image: Chrome Warning]

When I connect to my service over SSL, I get a warning about using obsolete crypto, and found [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83831/google-chrome-your-connection-to-website-is-encrypted-with-obsolete-cryptograph) explaining how I need to change my server to only use modern crypto algorithms.

1. Am I able to set required algorithms with Karaf/Pax like setting the SSL configuration below? (preferred)
2. Or do I need to do custom trust management as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277328/how-can-i-register-webservice-through-osgi-karaf-api-with-custom-trustmanager/27280538#comment43043015_27280538) with Jetty and information from [this page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_SSL) to [enable/disable cipher suites](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/CipherSuites)?

Here is the sample code I am using to setup the HTTPS port currently.

```
config:edit org.ops4j.pax.web;
config:property-set org.osgi.service.http.enabled false; 
config:property-set org.osgi.service.http.secure.enabled true;
config:property-set org.osgi.service.http.port.secure 9443; 
config:property-set org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.keystore.type JKS; 
config:property-set org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.keystore /etc/pki/tls/ks.jks;
config:property-set org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.password ************;
config:property-set org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.keypassword *********;
config:property-set org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.clientauthwanted false;
config:property-set org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.clientauthneeded false;
config:update;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your correct way of configuring the ssl connector you'll end up with a default SSL connector available from Jetty. Now you want to switch to TLS which is great. You don't need a custom trust management, right now the cipher suite can't be configured with a configuration parameter. Please open a new feature request at ops4j for this.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Do you have a suggestion for what I should do in the meantime? Looking around I found that Apache Felix supports: `org.apache.felix.https.jetty.ciphersuites.excluded` and `org.apache.felix.https.jetty.ciphersuites.included`; but is that not something I can use?

Comment: Also there was some info about configuring Apache's Virtual Host file, but it seems like that may be generated in Karaf?

Comment: the org.apache.felix* properties are for the felix implementation of the http service, not related to pax-web and therefore won't work. You might want to try to "merge" a jetty.xml based configuration with the config based connector.

Comment: The Virtual Hosts are different and have nothing to do with "apache virtual host" definition files.

Comment: Thanks for steering me away from the virtual hosts.  Could you point me to any info that may help me approach a merged jetty configuration? I'm a newbie with karaf/jetty/pax-web.

Comment: np, I'll always try to get those bugs fixed asap :)

Comment: Just to note here (along with the link to the fix in the comment above), the format will look like "keyword  [space] comma,separated,cipher suites"  `org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.cyphersuites.included TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA`
`org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.cyphersuites.excluded SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA`

Comment: Just FYI, the property names are misspelled.  They should be:

org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.ciphersuites.included
org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.ciphersuites.excluded

All possible configurations are here:
https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/blob/master/pax-web-runtime/src/main/resources/OSGI-INF/metatype/metatype.xml

Answer (score 1):

In the org.ops4j.pax.web.cfg, you can set the following settings for example:

```
org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.ciphersuites.included=TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.ciphersuites.excluded=TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.protocols.included=TLSv1.2
```

You can also use the technique the OP used in his answer:

```
config:edit org.ops4j.pax.web;
config:property-set org.ops4j.pax.web.ssl.protocols.included TLSv1.2
```